# CORS policy blocking POST requests to API

Tags: vue.js, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to deploy an app I created online. The UI is created using vue.js and it's calling a API written in dotnet core. I'm running dotnet core 2.2.

The web project and the API are on different servers and accessible under different domains, the web project is hosted on Netlify if that makes a difference. I managed to set up the CORS policy so that locally everything worked fine. When I access the app on the webserver I receive CORS errors whenever I post data. My `GET` and `DELETE` requests work just fine.

Here is my CORS policy

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Default", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins(/* the domain where my web project is hosted */);

            builder.AllowAnyMethod();
            builder.AllowAnyHeader();
            builder.AllowCredentials();
        });
    });
}
```

So I'm thinking everything should be fine. `AllowCredentials` is required because I'm using SignalR which otherwise wouldn't work.

The error message in the dev tools is

> POST [my api endpoint] 400 (Bad Request)
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '[my api endpoint]' from origin 'https://xxx.netlify.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

And when I look into the console where my dotnet project is running I see the following error message

> Connection id "0HLQNTR19GE1T" bad request data: "Requests with 'Connection: Upgrade' cannot have content in the request body."
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Requests with 'Connection: Upgrade' cannot have content in the request body.
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException.Throw(RequestRejectionReason reason)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1MessageBody.For(HttpVersion httpVersion, HttpRequestHeaders headers, Http1Connection context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.CreateMessageBody()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)

So far I tried setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*"` Header via the netlify.toml file, using the `[EnableCors]` attribute on my controller action. I edited my AJAX request (axios) and set `withCredentials: true` and in general played around with the CORS policy a lot. Unfortunately without luck and I'm running out of ideas.

I'm happy about any suggestions.

Comment: Is your API server behind an nginx proxy by any chance?

Comment: yes. I have a reverse proxy to run the API on port 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your nginx.conf file for a line called `proxy_set_header` and set it to `Connection $http_connection`

Comment: It works! That's awesome, thank you so much. I don't think I'd ever thought about nginx being the issue here..

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked! Anytime you're dealing with a reverse proxy in between your front end and backend it's a good idea to throw nginx or apache onto the end of your search. Can't tell you how many times the problem has been my proxy eating my headers haha.